# modelAttribute in mustache Templates (Spring-Boot App) / binding form data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mustache

I'm working on a Spring-Boot app which handles form data. My question is, if there is a possibility to bind the form data in case of validation errors for example.

My case:

form.mustache:

```
<form action="/form/basisdata" method="post" name="basisdata">
<label for="contactName">Kontakt / Ansprechpartner*:</label>
        <input type="text" name="contactName"/>
<label for="emailAddress">E-Mail-Adresse*:</label>
        <input type="text" name="emailAddress"/>
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{_csrf.token}}" />
<button class="a-button" type="submit">Weiter</button>
</form
```

Controller method:

```
@PostMapping("/basisdata")
public ModelAndView setFormBasisdata(@Valid @ModelAttribute("basisdata") Basisdata basisdata, BindingResult bindingResult, Map<String, Object> model) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        List<Error> errorList = getErrors(bindingResult);
        model.put("errors" , errorList);
        model.put("basisdata", basisdata);
        return new ModelAndView("formBasisdata", model);
    }

    return new ModelAndView("formNextStep", model);
}
```

In case of validation errors we're returning correctly to the same form page and shows the list of errors. But the form stays empty. I would prefer it, if the form is prefilled with the values that were entered before.

Is returning ModelAndView in that case the wrong option?

In jsp templates using spring forms there is an attribute in the form, that specifies the model (modelAttribute) in thymeleaf it's th:object. Is there something that I need to change / add in my mustache template?

Comment: Remove the attribute named `model` and use `bindingResult.getModel()` instead. Everything is already there so no need to add `basisdata` and `errors` again.

Comment: Hi,
if I don't add the  errors, I won't be able to see the error messages in the frontend. Unfortunately text inputs are still empty after form submit with validation errors. (I removed the model Map from the method signature and use bindingResult.getModel() as you suggested.)

Comment: The errors are part of the model (but probably in a different structure as you expect).

Comment: I suspect you need to add `setExposeSessionAttributes` to `true`. Unless there is another way to obtain the session attributes. Then you can obtain the user as a regular attribute.